# Probability inequality problem about discrete random variable

Tags: probability-theory

Here is the problem.

> Let X be a discrete random with $\ E(X) = 0$ and $\  \text{Var}(X) = \sigma^2 < \infty  $. 
>  
>   Show that
>   $$
> P(X \geq a) \leq \frac{s^2}{s^2 + a^2}
> $$
>   for all $\ a > 0$.

I attended to use Chebyshev's inequality to solve it. And I get
$$
P(|X| \geq a) \leq \frac{s^2}{a^2}
$$
Then I don't know how to remove the absolute sign and get the result. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Do you mean $\sigma^2$ instead of $s^2$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Cantelli.27s_inequality

Answer (score 4):

For all $a$, we have
$$a=E[a-X]\le E[(a-X)I_{X<a}]$$
where $I$ is the indicator function.Use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have
$$a^2\le E[(a-X)^2]E[I^2_{X<a}]=E(a-X)^2P\{X<a\}
=(Var(X)+a^2)P\{x<a\}$$
so
$$P\{X\ge a\}=1-P\{X<a\}\le\dfrac{\sigma^2}{\sigma^2+a^2}$$